# Combined Text Files With a Delimiter to One line

Tags: regex, linux, text

I'm looking to combined multiple text files with a delimiter and their file name then erase all of the new lines and have everything on one line.

So far I can do this with two different scripts:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' -print | while read filename; do echo "±±±±± $filename"; cat "$filename"; done > files.txt;
```

and

```
tr '\n' ' ' < files.txt  > desiredoutput.txt
```

I've tried combining these two with no avail.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to combine them would be to do the `tr` on each `$filename` in place of `cat`:

```
find -type f -name '*.txt' -print | while read filename
 do echo -n "±±±±± $filename "  # The -n suppresses the \n at the end of the line.
    tr '\n' ' ' < "$filename"
    echo -n ' '  # Add a terminating delimiter
 done > desiredoutput.txt;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  At first I accidentally looped it somehow and made a 3gb txt file haha.  But it's all working now!  Thanks

Comment: Actually this one folder I have does cause it to enter an Infinite loop and useing all of my hard drive.  Any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: Perhaps the `find` is finding the output file and using it as an input file (it matches `'*.txt'`).